# pcb connector for 3mm holes

Tags: pcb, connector

I have a pcb with two 3mm holes for the positive and negative from a 12V battery. I need some sort of connector to solder in the holes for wires to attach to. The holes are separated so I must have two individual connectors rather than 1 connector with two connection points. I was thinking of pin headers but they seem to be only suitable for smaller holes. The holes are too wide to attach the wires directly. Whatever I use must be narrow as the holes are quite close (either side) to a capacitor.

Comment: Perhaps add a picture of the board to clarify what you are refering to. In addition, actual product suggestions are not what the EE stackExchange is there for. We can perhaps give you general solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you could use one of the battery connector plugs with pigtails and solder the wires into the holes. eg "EC5"

Comment: Maybe a banana plug soldered in place